# Generating TIFF in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, tiff

I have not been able to find any info on creating a TIFF on iOS (or converting a jpg or getting a TIFF representation from a UIImage) in the search engines.

I need to create a TIFF image, preferably from my UIIMage or converting from a jpg representation.  I see PNG and JPG support but nothing for TIFF images.

The service I am uploading images to requires TIFF (signature capture).

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), which has been compiled for iOS. This will handle the conversion for you.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try!  I had not known it was available for iOS.  I will report back.